# How to remove a href that is listed under div tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I'm modifying a part of my wordpress theme and I have come across an issue. I want to remove the ability to click on a link though I do not have the ability to modify the class names or set ID tags

HTML:

```
<div class="one">
  <a href="foobar.com">foobar.com</a>
</div>
```

I have tried to remove the functionality by writing this JavaScript:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("one")
  .getElementsByTagName("a")
  .removeAttribute("href");
```

However this method does not work, am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use css.

```
.one a {
    pointer-events: none;
  }
```

and you can also remove the hand cursor by adding `cursor: default;`

Answer (score 2):

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].removeAttribute("href");
```

```html
<div class="one">
    <a href="foobar.com">foobar.com</a>
</div>
```

No need to target `.one` first. Just target by `getElementsByTagName` but remember that this returns an array of elements, so you need to reference the index of the element you want to remove.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].removeAttribute("href");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to select only the links in the "one" class, you'll need to index into what you get back from `getElementsByClass` then call children and index into that:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("one")[0].children[0].removeAttribute("href")
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can do it this way:**

```js
     document.getElementById("text").onclick = function(){
  
    var clickStatus = true; // Change this to true if you want to enable the link.
  
 if (clickStatus){
      window.location = "http://foobar.com";
 }
   
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
   <section id="text">foobar.com</section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It will generate `Type Error` because `getElementsByClassName` function will return a node list not a single node so you will need to do the following:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("one")[0]
.getElementsByTagName("a")[0]
.removeAttribute("href");
```

or

```
document.querySelector(".one a").removeAttribute("href");
```

Any method of the above will solve your problem

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to disable the Href functionalities here.
Please use Jquery :

```
$('.one > a').on('click',function(e){    
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

Hope this will work for you